# Starting jupyter from within a conda env vs. outside of conda envs

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, conda

What is the difference between **opening *jupyter lab*(or *notebook*) from WITHIN a specific `conda` env** vs. **opening from OUTSIDE of any `conda` envs?**

When I open *jupyter* from **WITHIN** a specific `conda` env, it works all fine, however
when I open *jupyter* from **OUTSIDE** of any `conda` envs and try to select a kernel for `my_env`, *jupyter* fails with the error below:

What might be the cause of this phenomena?

```
.
.
  File "C:\Users\shinji\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

---

- starting *jupyter* from WITHIN

-In *command prompt*,
`C:\Users\shinji\dir> activate my_env`

`(my_env) C:\Users\shinji\dir> jupyter lab`

-After *jupyter lab* opens,
Select kernel: `my_env`

---

- starting *jupyter* from OUTSIDE

-In *command prompt*,
`C:\Users\shinji\dir> jupyter lab`

-After *jupyter lab* opens,
Select kernel: `my_env`

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the difference is that

```
activate my_env
```

will, among other things, modify the `PATH` environment variable, which you can check by doing (when in your base env)

```
 echo %PATH%
 conda activate my_env
 echo %PATH%
```

The `PATH` variable is crucial here, as it is the default location where windows applications look for dlls that they are loading. Hence the error message when trying to select the kernel that belongs to `my_env` from outside the env you installed it in:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: Thanksfor clarifying. I am still confused partly because for some other envs, I can use their kernels on jupyter opened from OUTSIDE, without any errors. It's just this `my_env` that throws the error. Could this phenomena be attributed to something else other than `Path` difference?

Comment: Maybe check the version of `zeromq` by running `conda list` for the `my_env` and some other env for which it works. The error message indicates that `zmq` is not able to locate neccessary DLLs from the current `PATH`. It could be that for two envs that have the same `zmq` version installed you could launch the kernel of env A while in env B, as the `zmq` from A that is used can find the DLLs it needs in the PATH of env B that is activated

Comment: Interestingly, other envs that work fine do not have `zeromq` installed in the first place, only `my_env` does. Maybe I used a different command or channel when installing `jupyterlab`. I should probably stick to opening jupyter from within envs and launch the corresponding kernel to each env. Do you open jupyter before activating any env so that you can switch between different kernels OR open jupyter after activating a specific env and only use the kernel of the activated env? What's the convention?

Comment: Seems like that might be the issue. Might be a different jupyterlab version with diferent dependencies. I find it ususally best to activate an environment and then start jupyter, because other packages are otherwise also not able to locate neccessary dlls (for me that is `numpy` or `matplotlib`. In case you need jupyter from different envs, simply activate them and run another instance

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up a lot of things for me! Really appreciated it.